# Summarising Data Islands

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression, gaps-and-islands

I've been doing a lot of reading regarding data islands and summarising using a CTE or lots of subqueries.  Most seem to rely on clever math with the date, which looks cool, but I don't think it would work for me.

We have many vehicle data loggers sending in status updates on various schedules.  I'm looking for a faster, non-loop based way to summarise certain statuses.

- **NodeId**   Device identifier
- **LogId**    Log Entry PK
- **AssembledTime**    When the record was assembled on the device
- **ReceivedTime** When the record was received on the server
- **Speed**    Speed at time of logging
- **StatusText**   Can contain multiple keywords

The data is normally processed at end of trip.(Ignition on to ignition off)  There is a LogTrips that provides a NodeId, StartTime and EndTime.  Currently I loop through the Log entries, ordered by AssembledTime, looking for StatusText like %whatever%.  I do this a few times, based on the clients preferred statuses. eg: (StatusText like '%seatbelt%' or StatusText like '%s/b%') and lm.Speed > 10, for people driving without a seatbelt

After some reading I can see that I can use row_number() to create a proper sequential record, and extract the statuses wanted using case when...end

```
SELECT  RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.AssembledTime),
            l.NodeId,
            l.LogId,
            l.AssembledTime,
            lm.Speed,
            lm.StatusText,
            StatusSpeed = CASE WHEN lm.StatusText like '%speed%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
            StatusAccident = CASE WHEN lm.StatusText like '%accident%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,  --impact?
            StatusSeatbeltDriving = CASE WHEN (lm.StatusText like '%seatbelt%' or lm.StatusText like '%s/b%') and lm.Speed > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,  
            StatusSeatbeltIdle = CASE WHEN (lm.StatusText like '%seatbelt%' or lm.StatusText like '%s/b%') and lm.Speed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            Status4wd = CASE WHEN (lm.StatusText like '%4wd%' or lm.StatusText like '%4x4%')  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    FROM    Ctrack6.dbo.Logs l 
    JOIN    Ctrack6.dbo.LogMobiles lm on l.LogId = lm.LogId 
    WHERE   l.NodeId = @NodeId
    AND     l.AssembledTime between @TripStart AND @TripEnd
```

This would give me a list of all logs for a devices trip, in sequence:

```
RowNumber   NodeId  LogId   AssembledTime   Speed   StatusText  StatusSpeed StatusAccident  StatusSeatbeltDriving   StatusSeatbeltIdle  Status4wd   IsProcessed
1   3099    308815155   2015-05-26 11:05:43.000 0   Start up    0   0   0   0   0   0
2   3099    308815156   2015-05-26 11:05:55.000 0   Driving 0   0   0   0   0   0
3   3099    308815157   2015-05-26 11:06:25.000 10  Driving 0   0   0   0   0   0
4   3099    308815158   2015-05-26 11:06:45.000 11  Driving 0   0   0   0   0   0
5   3099    308815344   2015-05-26 11:07:15.000 0   Driving 0   0   0   0   0   0
6   3099    308815345   2015-05-26 11:07:16.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
7   3099    308815477   2015-05-26 11:07:19.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
8   3099    308815479   2015-05-26 11:07:24.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
9   3099    308815481   2015-05-26 11:07:29.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
10  3099    308815482   2015-05-26 11:07:34.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
11  3099    308815598   2015-05-26 11:07:39.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
12  3099    308815599   2015-05-26 11:07:44.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
13  3099    308815600   2015-05-26 11:07:49.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
14  3099    308815601   2015-05-26 11:07:54.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
15  3099    308815729   2015-05-26 11:08:00.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
16  3099    308815730   2015-05-26 11:08:05.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
17  3099    308815731   2015-05-26 11:08:10.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
18  3099    308815732   2015-05-26 11:08:15.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
19  3099    308816439   2015-05-26 11:08:45.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
20  3099    308816440   2015-05-26 11:09:15.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
21  3099    308816441   2015-05-26 11:09:45.000 0   Seatbelt    0   0   0   1   0   0
22  3099    308816442   2015-05-26 11:10:07.000 0   Ignition off    0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The desired results would summarise rows 6-21.  With

- **NodeId** - NodeId of the device
- **StartLogId** LogId of Row 6
- **EndLogId** LogId of Row 21
- **EventStartTime** AssembledTime of Row 6
- **EventEndTime** Assembled Time of Row 21
- **EventType** 'Seatbelt'

If there were multiple islands, there would be multiple summaries

I'm just not getting what I could group by to make my islands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution on the following page: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

More specifically:

Added two Table variables

```
declare @logs table
(
    LogId int PRIMARY KEY,
    RowNumberAll int,
    RowNumberNode int,
    NodeId int,
    AssembledTime datetime,
    Speed int,
    StatusText varchar(200),
    StatusSpeed bit,
    StatusAccident bit,
    StatusSeatbeltDriving bit,
    StatusSeatbeltIdle bit,
    Status4wd bit,
    UNIQUE(Nodeid, RowNumberNode),
    UNIQUE(RowNumberAll)
)

declare @results table
(
    EventType varchar(50),
    NodeId int,
    StartSeqNo int,
    EndSeqNo int,
    LogCount int,
    UNIQUE(NodeId, StartSeqNo, EventType)
)
```

Added an additional column RowNumberNode to query.

```
RowNumberNode = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NodeId ORDER BY l.AssembledTime),
```

Modified the example a bit to work with my code.  I have 1 of these blocks for each status I want sunmmarised

```
INSERT INTO @results (EventType, NodeId, StartSeqNo, EndSeqNo, LogCount)
SELECT 'Speed', 
    NodeId, 
    StartSeqNo=MIN(RowNumberNode),      
    EndSeqNo=MAX(RowNumberNode), 
    LogCount=MAX(RowNumberNode) - MIN(RowNumberNode) + 1
FROM 
(
    SELECT NodeId, 
            RowNumberNode,
            rn=RowNumberNode-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NodeId     ORDER BY RowNumberNode)
    FROM @logs
    WHERE StatusSpeed=1
) a
GROUP BY NodeId, rn
--HAVING MIN(RowNumberNode) - MAX(RowNumberNode) > 0
ORDER BY NodeId, StartSeqNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

> > What do I group by?

The way I do this is flag each 'state change' with a 1. Then I do a running total on that field. That gives you an incrementing unique number for each 'group' which you can group on.

Personally I always load these things into a staging table for processing rather than try and use a bunch of inline subselects for two reasons:

1. For various reasons it's often faster (you can create specific indexes, you can optimise the data size)
2. You can add lots of extra 'helper' columns that allow you to debug this notoriously complex processing (i.e. mapping your free text comment to a known status)

Also, being in a staging table you can use constructs like this to 'gobble up' the islands:

```
SELECT 1

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT<> 0
BEGIN

    UPDATE TGT
    SET ChangeColumn=1 
    FROM YourTable TGT
    INNER JOIN YourTable PriorRow
    WHERE PriorRow.RowNum-1 = TGT.RowNum
    AND   PriorRow.State = TGT.State
    AND   ChangeColumn=0

END
```

If your run this it keeps running until all state changes are found and flagged

Comment: I tried running this over a days worth of data (371444 rows).  Hadn't returned after an hour, so I killed it.

Comment: Sounds like you already found your solution. Anyway for 371,444 rows, I guess there is an endless loop occuring and logic in the UPDATE would need to be fixed as it should stop updating when it's no onger required.